# why i can't see any options of categories in select menu?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i am using this code to have the categories form the database to the select menu , but it is not working.

```
<select
        onChange={handleChange("category")}
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Category"
      >
        <option>Select</option>
        {categories &&
          categories.map((cate, index) => {
            <option key={index} value={cate._id}>
              {cate.name}
            </option>
          })}
      </select>
```

i have all the categories from the database in the 'categories' array , i have tested it in console but i cannot see in select options

Answer (score 0):

You have to return JSX from the function you passed into `categories.map`. Since you are not returning anything, by default any javascript function will return `undefined`. That means `categories.map` is producing an array of `undefined`.

```
{categories &&
   categories.map((cate, index) => {
     return (
       <option key={index} value={cate._id}>
         {cate.name}
       </option>
     );
   }
)}
```

You can also implicitly return the JSX

```
{categories &&
   categories.map((cate, index) => (
       <option key={index} value={cate._id}>
         {cate.name}
       </option>
     )
)}
```